# How to receive multi c2dm notifications?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I'm using C2DM to send notification for my android App and it is working fine. But i am able to get only one notification at a time. so that while receiving the notification, it replaces previously received notification.

So how to receive multiple C2DM notification, like receiving normal SMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the messages different `collapse_key`s. Here's an excerpt from the [official docs](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/android/c2dm/index.html#push):

> An arbitrary string that is used to collapse a group of like messages
>   when the device is offline, so that only the last message gets sent to
>   the client. This is intended to avoid sending too many messages to the
>   phone when it comes back online. Note that since there is no guarantee
>   of the order in which messages get sent, the "last" message may not
>   actually be the last message sent by the application server. Required.

[On a side note; you are not *supposed* to use the push messages too frequently](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/android/c2dm/quotas.html):

> Are you sending C2DM messages too frequently? If you need to
>   communicate with your application frequently over a short period of
>   time, C2DM is probably not the best solution. Instead, consider
>   implemeting XMPP or your own protocol to exchange messages, and use
>   C2DM only to send the initial notification.

Comment: No am not sending C2DM messages too frequently. My problem is, when i received a notification but remains unread, after 5 minutes when i send another notification, the new notification replaces the previous one.

Comment: Very good, using the `collapse_key` is the way to go though. If two messages has the same collapse_key the older one will be overwritten.